# Google App Engine: Assigning domain names to specific paths of your app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm building a website for a client who wants to showcase his company's products.His company has like 5 sub companies. For example, his company is called Nazzy industries (named after Nazzy his endeared grandmama). Nazzy Industries has 5 sub-companies. One distributes snacks, one sells safety equipment, one sells cars.

I"m going to build a large website but I may want to serve sub companies in their own domains in the future. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a little workaround.
You need to first verify ownership of all the domain names (through the google cloud console). Console > AppEngine > Settings > Custom Domains

In the application you will need to check from which domain the request is incoming. All languages should support that already, a simple thing.

This information is not verified from zero to production. But almost sure this can be done this way.

Answer (score 0):

For both Standard and Flexible you set up your domain names in `Products & Services > App Engine > Settings > Custom Domains` using [wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#wildcard_mappings) and [subdomains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#using_subdomains) in following ways:

- Have services named cars, snacks, etc, which will be mapped to cars.nazzy.com, snacks.nazzy.com, etc.
- Later you can separate them to different domains, like: ncars.com, nsnacks.com .

You can set it up in one way and then transition to the other without changing code or configuration of your applications at all.